# How do I see vm creation times from the Virtual Machine Manager GUI? h

Tags: gui, kvm-virtualization

I simply want to know the date / time for each VM I have created, and the last time they were booted.  Seems like an intuitive thing that any sane GUI programmer would have included???

I have 4 vms, created on late model Ubuntu 20.04 KVM Virtual Machine Manager less than a month ago, and cannot see date/times for them.  Please advise.  I want to use this to actually manage vms.

Comment: You can do that from within each OS, generally speaking. For example, your last reboot can be gleaned with the `last` command. Installation date isn't too hard to find, either.